# How to provide a way to use custom encryption in Android library?

Tags: android, encryption

I have a library that has default ways to encrypt stuff that it uses, which means user just need to provide a string as a key.

```
lib.encryption("key")
lib.doEncryptedStuff() // use default encryption
```

I want to allow users use custom encryption, including those that implement custom java crypto providers. My question is, what should be the correct way to ask user for such encryption methods? For now I came with idea to request two ciphers - one for encryption and one for decryption.

```
// create and init() ciphers here
lib.encryption(cipherEncrypt, cipherDecrypt)
lib.doEncryptedStuff() // use custom ciphers
```

But I'm unsure whether this is the correct way. Are Ciphers enough? Or should I provide interface for encryption for user to implement? I remember there being issues with reusing IV, which means cipher re-initialization?

Another issue that I'm facing is that it's really hard for me to generalize interface. Like AES with ECB will work with encrypt()/decrypt() methods, but with CBC it requires IV, which could also be stored inside encrypted data. What a mess.

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot help you directly, but I feel obliged to make you aware of this post: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged It is basic security 101 that you do NOT want to create your own encryption. Just putting it out here. Make with this info what you want :)

Comment: @muetzenflo thanks for the reply! But by "custom" encryption I mean standardized encryption which is not included in Java library by default. Like Russian's Kuznyechik via Cryptopro library. It is added as library to android application and we need support to use those encryption libraries inside our library when needed. Or, for example, if organization that uses library requires something except AES.

Comment: Are we talking about a JVM (Java/Kotlin) library, or a C library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I've nailed it. I used Stream-like approach, but not tied to streams. It allows to use any encryption user needs by passing interface as parameter.

My interface:

```
interface Encryption
{
  fun encrypt(
    read:  (buffer: ByteArray, count: Int) -> Int,
    write: (buffer: ByteArray, count: Int) -> Unit
  )

  fun decrypt(
    read:  (buffer: ByteArray, count: Int) -> Int,
    write: (buffer: ByteArray, count: Int) -> Unit
  )
}
```

Example implementation:

```
// init cipher and buffer
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE)
val buffer = ByteArray(BLOCK_SIZE)
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keystore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null))

// write iv (when decrypting read IV from beginning)
val iv = cipher.iv
write(iv, iv.size)

// write data
var count = 0
while (true)
{
  count = read(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE)

  if (count < BLOCK_SIZE)
    break

  val encrypted = cipher.update(buffer, 0, count)
  write(encrypted, encrypted.size)
}

// flush remains
if (count > 0)
{
  val final = cipher.doFinal(buffer, 0, count)
  write(final, final.size)
}
```

Example usage (input and output are streams):

```
encryption.encrypt(
  read = { buffer, count ->
    input.read(buffer, 0, count)
  },
  write = { buffer, count ->
    output.write(buffer, 0, count)
  }
)
```